# How do I do an OR filter in a Django query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to be able to list the items that either a user has added (they are listed as the creator) or the item has been approved.

So I basically need to select:

```
item.creator = owner or item.moderated = False
```

How would I do this in Django? (preferably with a filter or queryset).

Answer (score 836, accepted):

There is [`Q`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects that allow to complex lookups. Example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Item.objects.filter(Q(creator=owner) | Q(moderated=False))
```

Comment: how could this be done programmatically?  So, for example be able to have `for f in filters: Item.objects.filter(Q(creator=f1) | Q(creator=f2) | ...)`

Comment: @AlexisK  Use something like `reduce(lambda q, f: q | Q(creator=f), filters, Q())` to create the big Q object.

Comment: @alexis: you could also do `Item.objects.filter(creator__in=creators)`, for example.

Comment: If you wondering (like me) where `|` being used as OR operator comes from, it's actually the set union operator. It's also used (not here) as bitwise OR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988665/pipe-character-in-python

Answer (score 184):

You can use the | operator to combine querysets directly without needing Q objects:

```
result = Item.objects.filter(item.creator = owner) | Item.objects.filter(item.moderated = False)
```

(edit - I was initially unsure if this caused an extra query but @spookylukey pointed out that lazy queryset evaluation takes care of that)

Comment: To find out which queries are executed on a given request, you can use the debug-toolbar Django application.  It's made of awesome and win.

Comment: I was testing this from the shell. Is there a way to trace the queries for the above line directly from the shell?

Comment: do 'from django.db import connection' and use 'connection.queries'. This requires DEBUG=True. BTW, you should know that [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) and this hits the DB just once.

Comment: Could exclude be used with negated comparisons?

Comment: can this result in duplicates in the result queryset?

Comment: More specifically query sets tend to hit the DB only when you try to index into them, otherwise you're just building a query.

Comment: This is great for my use where I have a loop that produces QuerySets for a bunch of different scenarios, but the last one has an extra case that needs tacked on with an OR. `queries[-1] = queries[-1] | final`

Answer (score 95):

It is worth to note that it's possible to add **Q** expressions.

For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q(first_name='mark')
query.add(Q(email='mark@test.com'), Q.OR)
query.add(Q(last_name='doe'), Q.AND)

queryset = User.objects.filter(query)
```

This ends up with a query like :

```
(first_name = 'mark' or email = 'mark@test.com') and last_name = 'doe'
```

This way there is no need to deal with *or* operators, reduce's etc.

Comment: But it's easier to write `query |= Q(email='mark@test.com')`?

Comment: @Alex78191, different folks have different coding style preferences, but besides that, this usage allows the operator (`Q.OR` or `Q.AND`) to be given as an argument to a function that may be required to handle both scenarios.

Answer (score 41):

You want to make filter dynamic then you have to use Lambda like

```
from django.db.models import Q

brands = ['ABC','DEF' , 'GHI']

queryset = Product.objects.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(brand=item) for item in brands]))
```

`reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(brand=item) for item in brands])` is equivalent to

```
Q(brand=brands[0]) | Q(brand=brands[1]) | Q(brand=brands[2]) | .....
```

Comment: Perfect answer for me! For python3, do `from functools import reduce` beforehand.

Comment: Why not to use `operator.or_` instead of `lambda x, y: x | y`?

Answer (score 31):

Similar to older answers, but a bit simpler, without the lambda...

To filter these two conditions using `OR`:

```
Item.objects.filter(Q(field_a=123) | Q(field_b__in=(3, 4, 5, ))
```

To get the same result programmatically:

```
filter_kwargs = {
    'field_a': 123,
    'field_b__in': (3, 4, 5, ),
}
list_of_Q = [Q(**{key: val}) for key, val in filter_kwargs.items()]
Item.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, list_of_Q))
```

`operator` is in standard library: `import operator`
From docstring:

> or_(a, b) -- Same as a | b.

For Python3, `reduce` is not a builtin any more but is still in the standard library: `from functools import reduce`

---

P.S.

Don't forget to make sure `list_of_Q` is not empty - `reduce()` will choke on empty list, it needs at least one element.

Answer (score 25):

Multiple ways to do so.

**1. Direct using pipe | operator.**

```py
from django.db.models import Q

Items.objects.filter(Q(field1=value) | Q(field2=value))
```

**2. using `__or__` method.**

```py
Items.objects.filter(Q(field1=value).__or__(field2=value))
```

**3. By changing default operation. (Be careful to reset default behavior)**

```py
Q.default = Q.OR # Not recommended (Q.AND is default behaviour)
Items.objects.filter(Q(field1=value, field2=value))
Q.default = Q.AND # Reset after use.
```

**4. By using `Q` class argument `_connector`.**

```py
logic = Q(field1=value, field2=value, field3=value, _connector=Q.OR)
Item.objects.filter(logic)
```

**Snapshot of Q implementation**

```py
class Q(tree.Node):
    """
    Encapsulate filters as objects that can then be combined logically (using
    `&` and `|`).
    """
    # Connection types
    AND = 'AND'
    OR = 'OR'
    default = AND
    conditional = True

    def __init__(self, *args, _connector=None, _negated=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(children=[*args, *sorted(kwargs.items())], connector=_connector, negated=_negated)

    def _combine(self, other, conn):
        if not(isinstance(other, Q) or getattr(other, 'conditional', False) is True):
            raise TypeError(other)

        if not self:
            return other.copy() if hasattr(other, 'copy') else copy.copy(other)
        elif isinstance(other, Q) and not other:
            _, args, kwargs = self.deconstruct()
            return type(self)(*args, **kwargs)

        obj = type(self)()
        obj.connector = conn
        obj.add(self, conn)
        obj.add(other, conn)
        return obj

    def __or__(self, other):
        return self._combine(other, self.OR)

    def __and__(self, other):
        return self._combine(other, self.AND)
    .............
```

Ref. [Q implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d3a64bea51676fcf8a0ae593cf7b103939e12c87/django/db/models/query_utils.py#L29)

Comment: very good overview over the options +1

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Basically it sounds like they act as OR

Answer (score -4):

```
Item.objects.filter(field_name__startswith='yourkeyword')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The question is specifically about building a query in Django to get records with field1 = 'value1' OR field2 == 'value2'. Your answer doesn't answer the question.