# OR operator in Django model queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to use an `OR` operator in the Django `filter()` function. Right now I have

```
contactlist = Contact.objects.filter(last_name__icontains=request.POST['query'])
```

but I also want to search by first name as well. For example:

```
contactlist = Contact.objects.filter(last_name__icontains=request.POST['query'] OR first_name__icontains=request.POST['query'])
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Filters - or?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

#### [Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q

Contact.objects.filter(Q(last_name__icontains=request.POST['query']) | 
                               Q(first_name__icontains=request.POST['query']))
```

Answer (score 13):

```
result = Contact.objects.filter(last_name__icontains=request.POST['query']) | Contact.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=request.POST['query'])
```

Comment: Please state what you're fixing in here. Posting only code quotes without summary is forbidden on stackoverflow.

Comment: Although I feel this syntax will force it to evaluate twice and so it'll execute two db queries instead of one (as described by the accepted answer)

Comment: For future reference, this syntax does NOT execute two database queries.

Comment: is this going to be executed as a single SQL request?