# Using OR operation in Django query

Tags: django

HI i am trying to use OR operator in django query. my code looks like:

```
hotels = models.Hotel.objects.filter(
        wed=True,
        county=hotel_main.county.id,
        (x=True)|(y=True)|(z=True),
        subscriptions__end_date__gte=datetime.date.today(),
        subscriptions__enquiry_count__lte=F('subscriptions__tier__enquiry_limit'),
    ).distinct()
```

I am trying to fetch a record having atleast one of the above x, y, z as true.
Any help ...thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Filters - or?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use the [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object. Something like this:

```
hotels = models.Hotel.objects.filter(
    wed=True,
    county=hotel_main.county.id,
    subscriptions__end_date__gte=datetime.date.today(),
    subscriptions__enquiry_count__lte=F('subscriptions__tier__enquiry_limit')).filter( Q(x=True) | Q(y=True) | Q(z=True)).distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
Contact.objects.filter(Q(last_name__icontains=request.POST['query']) | 
                           Q(first_name__icontains=request.POST['query']))
```

REF: [OR operator in Django model queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445174/or-operator-in-django-model-queries)

Comment: Both answers are right, but this one uses references and so should be accepted

Comment: yeah, move your Q statements to the last

Comment: @Jharwood the above answer uses reference too .. Hower over Q

Comment: oh, it wasn't obvious it was a link