# How can i select some columns with or operator in views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

How can i use `select` to select some columns with `or` operator in views.py?
I want to run the below query in views.py in Django:

```
SELECT name,family FROM student WHERE male = True OR degree=False
```

I used this ORM:

```
student = stu.objects.filter(male = True).values('name','family') | stu.objects.filter(degree = False).values('name','family')
```

Is this correct? Is there a way that i can remove duplicate `values('name','family')` in query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OR operator in Django model queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445174/or-operator-in-django-model-queries)

Comment: Does this divide fields into two groups? firstname on a side and family on another side?

Comment: No, this link is not my question. I want to select some fields too.

Comment: I'm not sure, just saw your title and send this link.

Comment: "I want to select some fields too." You already do that with `values()`. Combine that with `Q()` as shown in the question Alireza linked to get the complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Q objects:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

```
from django.db.models import Q

student = stu.objects.filter(Q(male = True) | Q(degree = False)).values('name','family')
```