# How to perform OR condition in django queryset?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to write a Django query equivalent to this SQL query:

```
SELECT * from user where income >= 5000 or income is NULL.
```

How to construct the Django queryset filter?

```
User.objects.filter(income__gte=5000, income=0)
```

This doesn't work, because it `AND`s the filters. I want to `OR` the filters to get union of individual querysets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do an OR filter in a Django query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/how-do-i-do-an-or-filter-in-a-django-query)

Answer (score 797, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q
User.objects.filter(Q(income__gte=5000) | Q(income__isnull=True))
```

[via Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: It would help if you add a print of object.query so we can relate both ORM and Query output to familiarize with it. BTW great example.

Comment: Is it better to use this type of query or perform two separate queries?

Comment: What if there are some other queries too along with this @lakshman

Comment: if both queries are same it will return duplicated queries. How to avoid that?

Comment: I just found how to avoid duplicate, after 6 min. Before the query use set() function. like: 
`set(User.objects.filter(Q(income__gte=5000) | Q(income__isnull=True)))`

Comment: @OsmanHamashool it is more efficient to append `.distinct()` so the database removes duplicates, rather than loading them all into Django then deduplicating in python.

Answer (score 84):

Because [QuerySets implement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/_modules/django/db/models/query/#QuerySet) the Python `__or__` operator (`|`), or union, it just works. As you'd expect, the `|` binary operator returns a `QuerySet` so `order_by()`, `.distinct()`, and other queryset filters can be tacked on to the end.

```
combined_queryset = User.objects.filter(income__gte=5000) | User.objects.filter(income__isnull=True)
ordered_queryset = combined_queryset.order_by('-income')
```

Update 2019-06-20: This is now fully documented in the [Django 2.1 QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#operators-that-return-new-querysets). More historic discussion can be found in [DjangoProject ticket #21333](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21333).

Comment: "undocumented" and "legacy" make me scared. I think it's safer to use the Q object, as detailed in the accepted answer here.

Comment: FYI,    order_by() and    distinct() can be applied to the piped queryset after they are combined

Comment: @carruthd thanks. I confirmed this as well. Will edit

Comment: Can the order_by() be applied to each individual queryset and then combined? So that the order for each condition is still maintained? For example, combined_queryset= User.objects.filter(income__gte=5000).order_by('income') | User.objects.filter(income__lt=5000).order_by('-income') ?

Comment: @noahandthewhale I don't know, but that would be very useful. Try it and let us know!

Comment: @Oatman: | operator is documented. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/: "In general, Q() objects make it possible to define and reuse conditions. This permits the construction of complex database queries using | (OR) and & (AND) operators; in particular, it is not otherwise possible to use OR in QuerySets."
I did not check documentation for earlier versions but pipe operator works from Django 1.1.4 at least (just tried).

Comment: if both queries are same it will return duplicated queries. How to avoid that?

Comment: I just found how to avoid duplicate, after 6 min. Before the query use set() function.
like:

`combined_queryset = set(User.objects.filter(income__gte=5000) | User.objects.filter(income__isnull=True))`

Comment: No @OsmanHamashool, I think this is a bad idea. It uses python's builtin `set` constructor to deduplicate the queryset from your database. Always use `.distinct()` on your queryset instead. That will run more efficiently within your database (SQL) and not burden your python process. Next time duckup "django queryset unique" to find the `.distinct()` method in the Django docs.

Comment: @hobs In my case I got `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`. So I the python's `set` works fine for me.

Comment: @OsmanHamashool yea you must not have a challenging throughput problem if you are using a database like MySQL that doesn't support DISTINCT ON. Switching to Postgres will give you ~100x speedup on that part of your app, if you ever do need it to run fast.

Comment: @hobs thanks, there is another down side for using python's `set`, which is that  you can't make ordering to your query sets. I'm planning to switch to postgres now, I will test it again and update the result in here.

Answer (score 31):

Both options are already mentioned in the existing answers:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
q1 = User.objects.filter(Q(income__gte=5000) | Q(income__isnull=True))
```

and

```py
q2 = User.objects.filter(income__gte=5000) | User.objects.filter(income__isnull=True)
```

However, there seems to be some confusion regarding which one is to prefer.

The point is that **they are identical on the SQL level**, so feel free to pick whichever you like!

The [Django ORM Cookbook](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/index.html) talks in some detail about this, here is the relevant part:

---

```py
queryset = User.objects.filter(
        first_name__startswith='R'
    ) | User.objects.filter(
    last_name__startswith='D'
)
```

leads to

```py
In [5]: str(queryset.query)
Out[5]: 'SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login",
"auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name",
"auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff",
"auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE ("auth_user"."first_name"::text LIKE R% OR "auth_user"."last_name"::text LIKE D%)'
```

and

```py
qs = User.objects.filter(Q(first_name__startswith='R') | Q(last_name__startswith='D'))
```

leads to

```py
In [9]: str(qs.query)
Out[9]: 'SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login",
 "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name",
  "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff",
  "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
  WHERE ("auth_user"."first_name"::text LIKE R% OR "auth_user"."last_name"::text LIKE D%)'
```

*source: [django-orm-cookbook](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/or_query.html)*

---

Answer (score 19):

Just adding this for multiple filters attaching to `Q` object, if someone might be looking to it.
If a `Q` object is provided, it must precede the definition of any keyword arguments. Otherwise its an invalid query. You should be careful when doing it.

an example would be

```
from django.db.models import Q
User.objects.filter(Q(income__gte=5000) | Q(income__isnull=True),category='income')
```

Here the OR condition and a filter with category of income is taken into account

Answer (score 5):

In order to add the conditions like "OR" or "AND" as we kind of use in sql queries we have this way as an example

```
from django.db.models import Q
Poll.objects.get(Q(question__startswith='Who'),Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 2)) | Q(pub_date=date(2005, 5, 6)))
```

this is equivalent to this sql query

```
SELECT * from polls WHERE question LIKE 'Who%'
AND (pub_date = '2005-05-02' OR pub_date = '2005-05-06')
```

I hope you are able to understand this properly that the "," is for "AND" operator and "|" is for the "OR" operator used in django.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to @lprsd's answer, you can use `or_` from `operator` library:

```
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(or_(Q(income__gte=5000), Q(income__isnull=True)))
```

`operator.or_` gets two values as arguments. To use three statements (or more) use `reduce`:

```
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(reduce(or_, Q(income__gte=5000), Q(income__lt=300), Q(income__isnull=True)))
```

This solution may be very helpful for queries generated dynamically (for example, using custom parameters from frontend input).

### Details

`operator` and `functools` are python standard libraries, which means you don't need to install them.

As you can see in a docstring of `or_` function, for `a` and `b` arguments it's

> same as a | b.

And `reduce`:

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence,
> from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.