# Dynamically setting OR filter values in Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567831/how-to-perform-or-condition-in-django-queryset) that to perform an OR operation on a queryset in Django, I can do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
User.objects.filter(Q(income__gte=5000) | Q(income=0))
```

Now suppose that instead of hard-coding the Q conditions within the filter call, I want to dynamically set them. That is, suppose I want to do something like this:

```
User.objects.filter(Q(income__gte=5000) [ONLY IF CONDITION A...] | Q(income=0) [ONLY IF CONDITION B...) | Q(name__contains="blah") [ONLY IF CONDITION C...])
```

Put differently, if the Q objects were a string, I'd want to append certain additional Q objects under certain conditions. This might be represented as:

```
q_string = ""
if conditionA:
    q_string += Q(income__gte=5000)
if conditionB:
    q_string = Q(income=0)

User.objects.filter(q_string)
```

But the stuff that goes into filter can't actually be a string, so this won't work. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
q1 = Q()
if conditionA:
    q1 |= Q(income__gte=5000)
if conditionB:
    q1 |= Q(income=0)

User.objects.filter(q1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
query_string = ""
if conditionA:
    query_string += Q(income__gte=5000)
if conditionB:
    query_string = Q(income=0)

User.objects.filter(query_string)
```