# converting sql query into django ORM function calls

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

i'm having a confusion of converting sql query in to django ORM function calls specially when 
converting this line of sql

AND  ( presentations.teaching_guide_text LIKE %s OR presentations.name LIKE %s  OR presentations.synopsis LIKE %s OR presentations.tags LIKE %s ) AND

i have tried doing this by ,

```
Presentations.objects.\
                        filter(deleted=0).\
                        filter(published=1).\
                        filter(academic_only=0).\
                        filter(video_type=1).\
                        filter(synopsis__icontains=search_item_array[i]).\
                        filter(tags__icontains=search_item_array[i]).\
                        filter(teaching_guide_text__icontains=search_item_array[i]).\
                        filter(name__icontains=search_item_array[i]).all()
```

but it doesn't work correctly. can anyone suggest me a solution to solve this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform OR condition in django queryset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567831/how-to-perform-or-condition-in-django-queryset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying successive `filters` effectively chains the filters with `AND`. What you want is [Q Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). See below:

```
from django.db.models import Q
# breaking them out for readability

q1 = Q(synopsis__icontains=search_item_array[i])
q2 = Q(tags__icontains=search_item_array[i])
q3 = Q(teaching_guide_text__icontains=search_item_array[i])
q4 = Q(name__icontains=search_item_array[i])

Presentation.objects.filter(q1|q2|q3|q4).filter(..).filter(..)
```

The first part of the filter does an `OR` against `q1,q2,q3,q4`, and the next lot of filters would be your traditional `AND`s.