# How to use a FilterUserMixin to filter one field or the other in Django

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm using FilterUserMixin for filtering data in a form. I have the model 'Game' which has attributes 'team1' and 'team2'. I want the filter to get all the games in the list where a certain team is either team1 or team2. My filter looks like this:

```
class GamesFilter(FilterUserMixin):
   name = django_filters.CharFilter(method='filter_name', label='Team name')
   def filter_name(self,queryset,name,value):
       queryset = queryset.filter(team2=value) | queryset.filter(team1=value)
       return queryset
   class Meta:
       model = Game
       fields = ('team1','team2',)
```

The filter does appear in the form, and it displays all teams registered (it's a ModelChoiceField, so a list, not a CharField to type in), and it correctly displays the games, but only those where the searched team is in the 'team1' field, not as 'team2'. Do you have any ideas?, I'm relatively new to this, and have tried a few unsuccesful things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. The name of the method (`filter_name`) was copied from a different filter of a different model, which had the attribute `name`. I changed the method name to `filter_team1` and suddenly it worked, even if in the `filter_team1` method itself I used both `team1` and `team2` attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Q
queryset = queryset.filter(Q(team2=value) | Q(team1=value))
```

You can check for reference: [How to perform OR condition in django queryset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567831/how-to-perform-or-condition-in-django-queryset)

Comment: I tried that, and it works the same, only when team1 is the team. I think it might have to do with the FilterUserMixin specifically, I don't really know how it works, but that's what my coworkers used for this project.