# Django. E-shop catalogue filters for goods

Tags: python, django

community!

I've stuck with developing filter system for e-shop on Django.
Some info:

- small scale (less than 2-3k items)
- django 1.7, postgresql.
- 1 level category structure. No nested categories

Model skeleton:

Category: - used for, you know, categories

- name

AttributeGroup: - used for filter name, ex. "Color"

- name

Attribute: - used for filter values to display, ex. "Red", "Green", etc.

- name
- attribute_group - foreign key to AttributeGroup

Item:

- name
- attributes - many-to-many to Attribute
- category - foreign key to Category.

So, one item can be in only one category. It can have many attributes from the same or different attribute groups. Very close or exact EAV model, but ok because hard caching is enabled.

Actually, my question consist of few:

1. What will be the best way to work with filters for such a scale? 
   I'm thinking of actual requests to relational DB tables with ORM filter stuff.
   Go noSql way with Postgre docs.
   Use solr with it's facets.

   2. How to recreate logic when there is OR logic inside one attribute group but AND logic between different attribute groups?

**EDITED**
Let's stick to the simplest way - pure Django ORM.

In category view I'm getting category_id and list of activated filters attributes.

so the items queryset will be something like that:
items = Item.objects.filter(category.id = category_id)

Now i need to use filter on this items queryset. attributes list holds ids of all activated attributes. For AND logic it's clear:
for attribute in attributes:
    items = items.filter(attribute.id = attribute)

But how can I make OR logic which should be between different groups of attributes?

Comment: Your question is unclear.. django makes it very easy for cross table relationships, what is your *exact* problem?

Comment: I'm able to recreate cross-table relationships. It doesn't seem optimal way to me. But okay, if I stick this architecture, what is the way to implement AND ad OR filtering for QuerySet than? Chaining .filter() gives me AND logic between attributes in different attribute groups. I'm not able to recreate OR logic between attributes in one group.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Filters - or?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)

Comment: Sayse looks like that but please look edit note in original post. The problem is that I don't know exact number of groups in advance so I can't put OR statements inside one line (Q(attribute=f1) | Q(attribute=f2) | ...). Need to put it in for loop.

Comment: Your question is still unclear.. Also, I'm pretty sure that django query sets have deferred execution so `.filter().filter()` would result in one query

Comment: Sayse, I didn't put enough attention to your reply :) Looks like the way to solve my problem.

Comment: Ah ok cool, (for reference its the first google result when you search for "django filter or" so I'm sure there are similar results for AND too)

Comment: Actually what I need is mix of OR and AND filters which is solved by Q lookups and link your provided tells how-to-do-it. Sometimes some help needed to ask right questions and remove complexity :) Big thanks!