# Django : How to filter in form

Tags: django, forms, filter

I have a model

```
class Demande_Expertise(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    material = models.CharField(_('material'), max_length=30)
    categorie =  models.ForeignKey("Category")

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
```

I have for the class Category the records : Alloys, Ceramic, Composite, Cu_based, Metals, Pure_metals, Ni_based

form

```
class Demande_ExpertiseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Demande_Expertise
        exclude =  ('etat',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Demande_ExpertiseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

template

```
<td>{{ form.categorie}}</td>
```

How do I get the form if I want to have for the template : Ceramic,  Cu_based, Ni_based ?

if I write in Demande_ExpertiseForm

```
self.fields['categorie'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(name__icontains="Cu_based")
```

I get only the filter for Cu_based

if I want the filter  for Ceramic, Cu_based, Ni_based 
how to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Filters - or?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)

Comment: @Sayse, I thin k the question is "how to use 3 objects in the form?"

Comment: It works with Category.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains="Ceramic") |  Q(name__icontains="Ni_based")  | .....) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Q'

```
from django.db.models import Q

self.fields['categorie'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains = 'Cu_based') | Q(name_icontains = 'Ceramic') | Q(name_icontains = 'Ni_based'))
```

Comment: for the first : too many values tu unpack and for the second I have an empty dropdown

Comment: Sorry my bad, I somehow thought it was an and operation.

Comment: self.fields['categorie'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(name__contains=word) for word in malist])) and with malist=['Cu_based', 'Ceramic', 'Ni_based', 'Ti_based']...... It works