# How to write a query with many ANDs and ORs with sum in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to write the following query in Django/Python:
in this query, I don't have a simple `or`, but I have many `and`s also and a `sum`

```
SELECT sum(value) FROM myapp_category
WHERE (name='difficulty' AND key='hard')
   OR (name= 'success' AND key='yes')
   OR (name= 'alternative' AND key='yes')
   OR (name= 'processing' AND key='good')
   OR (name= 'personal_touch' AND key='yes') `
```

and here's my model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   key = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   value = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name.encode('utf_8') + "_" + self.key.encode('utf_8')
```

and I don't want to use the raw sql, so what can I use for this ?

**Update Answer:**
Thanks for your answers, this is the complete answer:

```
    sum = Category.objects.filter(Q(name='difficulty',key=evaluation.difficulty) | 
Q(name='nogos',key=evaluation.nogos) | 
Q(name='success',key=evaluation.success) | 
Q(name='alternative',key=evaluation.alternative) | 
Q(name='processing',key=evaluation.processing) | 
Q(name='personal_touch',key=evaluation.personal_touch))
.aggregate(result=Sum('value'))

    score = float(sum['result'])
```

Comment: Do you have any models? Could you post them in your question?

Comment: I updated my question ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Filters - or?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)

Comment: in this question, I have not a simple `or`, I have many `and`s also.

Comment: @SafaaNa - Your answer doesn't differ much from the duplicate, as shown in Geo Jacobs answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum


Category.objects.filter(Q(name='difficulty',key='hard') | Q(name='success',key='yes') | Q(name='alternative',key='yes') | Q(name='processing',key='good') | Q(name='personal_touch',key='yes')).aggregate(Sum('value'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the output is an array and not a value. are you sure from this `.annotate(Sum('value'))`

Comment: In what basis you want to calculate the sum of values. How you want to group it?

Comment: just as the raw query in the question, I put all my condition in the `where` and just a simple `sum` without group will do it. in the end I want to save this sum in another table

Comment: I think I found it, using `aggregate `  instead of `annotate`

Comment: In which field you are saving, can you show me the table?

Comment: I updated the question with the complete query, I googled a little and found away to do it, many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

```
from django.db.models import Q

results = Category.objects.filter(
    Q(name="difficulty", key="hard") | Q(name= "success", key="yes") | 
    Q(name="alternative", key="yes")|Q(name="processing" AND key="good") | 
    Q(name="personal_touch",key="yes"))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it misses the `sum` part

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but maybe input for other ideas:

```
SELECT sum(value) FROM myapp_category
WHERE name+"/"+key IN (
  'difficulty/hard',
  'success/yes',
  'alternative/yes',
  'processing/good',
  'personal_touch/yes'
)
```

Problems:

- Also lists cannot be provided using parameters
- The query is slower because indexes cannot be used

Comment: I'm leaving the raw sql as a last solution.