# LEFT JOIN with OR condition in python django

Tags: python, django, join

All I want is to write the following SQL query in Python Django syntax. I researched a lot but could not get the result I want. Could you please help me.

```
    SELECT * FROM thread
    LEFT JOIN user
    ON (thread.user1_id = user.id OR thread.user2_id = user.id)
    WHERE user.id = 9
```

My model:

```
 class Thread(models.Model):
        last_message = models.TextField(max_length=100)
        user1_id = models.IntegerField()
        user2_id = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Filters - or?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)

Comment: the question is about join

Comment: The question is unclear, you should show what you have tried/researched so far to try to solve it. As well as the relevant parts of your models.

Comment: the question is clear and the answer will help thousands of beginners in the future. If you are an experienced Django developer, you can help me to find the solution, else you can wait till other developers will do it. Thanks.

Comment: @EducateYourself Can you post your user model and why you are not using straight-forward `ForeignKey` fields for `user1` and `user2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact query cannot be created using the Django ORM without resorting to some raw SQL. The problem is the OR in the join condition.

But, since your not selecting any rows from the user table, you can create a different query with the same results.

Start by defining your models using ForeignKeys.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Thread(models.Model):
    last_message = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User)
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'thread'  # otherwise it will be: appname_thread
```

Then you can preform the query.

```
from django.db.models import Q

threads = Thread.objects.filter(Q(user1__id=9) | Q(user2__id=9))
```

The resulting SQL will be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM thread
LEFT JOIN user AS user1
ON (thread.user1_id = user1.id)
LEFT JOIN user AS user2
ON (thread.user2_id = user2.id)
WHERE (user1.id = 9 OR user2.id = 9)
```

---

You can improve this by avoiding the join altogether.

```
# note the single underscore!
threads = Thread.objects.filter(Q(user1_id=9) | Q(user2_id=9))
```

Generating the following SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM thread
WHERE (user1_id = 9 OR user2_id = 9)
```

---

If you need to also obtain the user instances in the same query, in which case you really need the join, you have two options.

1. Either use the first query that includes joins and afterwards select the correct user based in the id in Python.

   ```
   for thread in threads:
       if thread.user1.id == 9:
           user = thread.user1
       else:
           user = thread.user2
   ```
2. Or use raw SQL to get the exact query you want. In this case, you can use the models without the ForeignKeys as you defined them.

   ```
   threads = Thread.objects.raw('''
              SELECT *, user.id AS user_id, user.name as user_name FROM thread
              LEFT JOIN user
              ON (thread.user1_id = user.id OR thread.user2_id = user.id)
              WHERE user.id = 9''')
   for thread in threads:
       # threads use the ORM
       thread.id
       # user fields are extra attributes
       thread.user_id
       thread.user_name
   ```

Comment: can I write request.user.id instead of 9 ?

Comment: Sure. However, you might want to use the user directly.
`Thread.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

Comment: I tried WHERE user.id = %s''', [request.user.id]) but it changes the values for all user.ids

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?