# Django Queryset

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I need to do something like this in order to match some objects.
This is the best way to do it?
Is possible to do it in a faster way?

```
if User.objects.filter(first_name=name, age=age).exists():
     user = User.objects.filter(first_name=name, age=age)
     function_x(user)
elif User.objects.filter(full_name__icontains=name, age=age).exists():
     user = User.objects.filter(full_name__icontains=name, age=age)
     function_x(user)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Filters - or?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use one of that condition, just use `Q` object, it allows you use logic `or` operator in your query.

```
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(Q(first_name=name) |
                    Q(full_name__icontains=name),
                    age=age)
```

In that case `|` means `or` and `,` means `and`, so age is required in both conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Given the variable name, I guess you are expecting the above query to return a single user. Thus, you can eliminate one more db hit using [`.first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#first):

`.first()` basically returns the first object matched by the queryset, or `None` if there isn't one. By this way, you don't have to perform `.exists()`.

```
user = User.objects.filter(Q(first_name=name) | Q(full_name__icontains=name), age=age).first()
```