# Filter in django with or condition

Tags: python, django

I want to use filter with `OR` condition in django while filtering the object data.

I have an object of a class and I have 3 or 4 fields on which basis I want to filter the data with `OR` condition in Django.

For example.

```
Obj = Books.objects.filter(title=title or price=price or description=description or author=author)
```

I think this is not the right way to perform filter.

What is the proper way to use `OR` condition in my django filter

Answer (score 6):

```
from django.db.models import Q

Obj = Books.objects.filter(Q(title=title) | Q(price=price) | Q(description=description) | Q(author=author))
```

Docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/739922/4808939

Comment: this is working if i pass all filed.If i pass one or two it gives me follwing error `Cannot use None as a query value`

Comment: In the above sample code if i pass only title it gives me error Cannot use None as a query value

Comment: @vikrant Do you want to allow blank query values? If so, you should sanitize them before passing them to the Q objects. Like so: `title = title or  ""`. This will replace the value with an empty string if it's `None`.

And if you don't care about blank values, then you should conditionally build your OR'ed together query.