# How to filter list of values from Table?

Tags: django

Consider I have model called **DemoModel** which consists of field named **demo_field** of type Char Field.

Now i have to query on the **demo_field** which has null values and 'demo'.

Example:

```
Class DemoModel(models.Model):
      demo_field = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
```

I have tried to query like

```
DemoModel.objects.filter(demo_field__in=[None,"demo"])
```

but i am able to get only records which having value as "demo".

I want to query it in single line is it possible? or anyother ways

Comment: `DemoModel.objects.filter(Q(demo__isnull=True) | Q(demo="demo"))` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/739776/1324033

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q
DemoModel.objects.filter(Q(demo__isnull=True) | Q(demo="demo"))
```