# Django filter multiple values

Tags: python, django

Anyone know why this `query_set` doesn't return any values for me? Using filter separately, it works perfectly, so it seems `.filter().filter()` together is the wrong approach to filter for 'either or'.

```
ticket_query = request.event.tickets.filter(status='on-sale').filter(status='paused').prefetch_related('ticket_tax')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Filters - or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

filter() with multiple parameters joins them with AND statements:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter

To perform OR queries in django you can use Q objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

ticket_query = request.event.tickets.filter(Q(status='on-sale') | Q(status='paused')).prefetch_related('ticket_tax')
```

More details here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

Answer (score 5):

`request.event.tickets.filter(status='on-sale')` returns all objects with `status='on-sale'`, and you are looking for objects with `status='paused'` in that list, which is why you are getting an empty queryset.

Chaining 2 filters is fine if it is a `ManyToManyField` where you can have multiple objects for the same field OR if you are chaining for 2 separate fields eg. `request.event.tickets.filter(status='on-sale').filter(is_available=True)`, which returns all tickets that are on sale **and** are available.

The simplest approach for this problem would be to use `__in` in the filter like this: `ticket_query = request.event.tickets.filter(status__in=['on-sale', 'paused']).prefetch_related('ticket_tax')`.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the many-to-many field guide.

Answer (score 4):

Chaining `filter` like you have done applies the subsequent filter to the queryset returned by the previous filter, i.e. it acts like an **AND** condition, not **OR**.

You can use the `|` operator to combine two queries:

```
ticket_query = request.event.tickets.filter(status='on-sale') | request.event.tickets.filter(status='paused')
```