# Filters chain rather than Q() combination in Queryset

Tags: django

I have an article model with m2m relationships to model Tag,

I intend to filter articles which have tags both "python" and "django"

I tried Q along with &

```
In [184]: from django.db.models import Q

In [185]: articles = Article.objects.filter(Q(tags__name="python") & Q(tags__name=
   ...: "django"))

In [186]: articles
Out[186]: <QuerySet []>
```

It return a null Queryset

Alternatively I tested

```
In [202]: articles = Article.objects.filter(Q(tags__name="python")).filter(Q(tags_
   ...: _name="django"))

In [203]: articles
Out[203]: <QuerySet [<Article: Test new tags>, <Article: Django Tutorial>]>
```

I worked and solved the problem.

However, I am very confused with the failing of `Q()&Q()`, should I alway utilize filter chain rather than Q() combination to avoid mistakes?

Comment: None of these will work, since Django assumes that you are talking about the *same* related tag, and a tag can not have as name `"python"` and `"django"` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `.filter(Q(tags__name="python") & Q(tags__name="django")`, you're asking `filter` to look for `Article`s with a related `Tag` that satisfies both `name="python"` and `name="django"` at the same time, which naturally can't be true.

By doing two separate `.filter()`s, the related Tags that satisfy the two conditions don't have to be the same one, since they are done on two separate querysets, so they will be able to find `Article`s that have a `Tag` whose `name` is `'python'`, and *another* `Tag` whose `name` is `'django'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`|`** operator (`Logical OR operator`) instead of **`&`** operator (`Logical AND operator`).
Try this,

```
from django.db.models import Q

Article.objects.filter(Q(tags__name="python") | Q(tags__name="django"))
                                            ^^^^^
```

See this So post also,
[Django Filters -OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)