# How to add a `or` condition filter in this prefetch_related query filter?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `qs` filter code like bellow:

```
qs2 = qs1.filter(ipv4s__ip=ip).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('ipv4s', queryset=IPv4Manage.objects.filter(ip=ip)))
```

now I want to add a `OR` logic filter in this filter.

how to add a `or` condition filter in this query filter?

I mean I want to add a or condition filter like this:
it will meet this

```
filter(ipv4s__ip=ip).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('ipv4s', queryset=IPv4Manage.objects.filter(ip=ip)))
```

condition or it will meet `ip='1.1.1.1'`.

How to make this come true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Filters - or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739776/django-filters-or)

Comment: So are your *questions* filtered too? Or only the prefetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `IN` query; you basically are selecting on `WHERE ip IN (<ip>, '1.1.1.1')` here:

```
filter(ipv4s__ip__in=(ip, '1.1.1.1')).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('ipv4s', queryset=IPv4Manage.objects.filter(ip__in=(ip, '1.1.1.1'))))
```

I'm assuming that you want to filter both the questions *and* the related `IPv4Manage` objects you are prefetching here, so both `ipv4s__ip__in` and `ip__in` filters are used in the above example. If you only wanted to filter, say, the prefetch query set, adjust accordingly.

The `queryset` parameter otherwise takes a standard `QuerySet` instance, so you can use [standard query constructing syntax with `Q()` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) to build more complex filters.

For example, if your query could not easily be satisfied with a `IN (...)` filter, then building on `OR` query works by using `Q()` filters combined with the `|` binary OR operator:

```
filter(Q(ipv4s__ip=ip) | Q(ipv4s__ip='1.1.1.1')).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('ipv4s', queryset=IPv4Manage.objects.filter(
        Q(ip=ip) | Q(ip='1.1.1.1')
    )))
```

Last but not least, if you are filtering your questions on the `ip` column of the `ipv4s` relationship, then you *don't need to further filter the pre-fetch on the same conditions*! That'll already be limited to the same filter, so it should be enough to just use:

```
filter(ipv4s__ip__in=(ip, '1.1.1.1')).prefetch_related('ipv4s')
```

The `.prefetch_related('ipv4s')` will prefetch the `IPv4Manage` objects that are connected to the questions that the `filter()` returned, so they have already been limited to the same `ip` column values.