# Django. How to reduce total number of coupons after each use

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am learning to develop a ecommerce website, I have a coupon model with used and max_value, which take care of max number of coupon available to use, I want to implement that in my views, such that if the coupon is redeemed more than the max_value(number of coupons), then it should show an error message. Whatever I have tried with my limited knowledge is resulting in errors.

How can I increment the 'used' in views?

This is in much more understandable way:

users(sellers) are able to create coupons. code is the alpha numeric  (which should be unique - i need to try work that out). The coupon can be used by anyone only once. max_value is set by the user who creates it, and each time someone uses coupons, the 'used' should get automatically appended. suppose there are 10 coupons, every time a customer uses one coupon, the 'used' should get incremented by 1 till it reaches max_value. if it reaches max_value, coupon should be invalid. This is what I am trying to achieve.

views

```
class AddCouponView(View, LoginRequiredMixin):
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    now = timezone.now()
    form = CouponForm(self.request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            code = form.cleaned_data.get('code')
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, complete=False)
            coupon_qs = Coupon.objects.filter(code__iexact=code, valid_from__lte=now,
                                            valid_to__gte=now)
            order_coupon = Order.objects.filter(coupon=coupon_qs.first(), user=self.request.user)

            if order_coupon:
                messages.error(self.request, 'You can\'t use same coupon again')
                return redirect('store:checkout')
            if coupon_qs:
                    order.coupon = coupon_qs[0]
                    order.save()
                    messages.success(self.request, "Successfully added coupon")
                    return redirect('store:checkout')
            else:
                messages.success(self.request, "Coupon Does not Exists")
                return redirect('store:checkout')

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.info(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect('store:checkout')
```

model

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
amount = models.FloatField()
valid_from = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
valid_to = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
max_value = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)], verbose_name='Coupon Quantity', null=True) # No. of coupon
used = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Thanks

Comment: it raised by objects.get() method, plz check the second one.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. Can you please elaborate? I didn't get you.

Comment: You can print the exception info, then you will get the cause.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the coupon model, correct me if I am wrong .. Coupon is assigned to a user, it has a code that categorize coupons. The user with the coupon can use it, when valid, max_value times on different orders.

Comment: Yes, users(sellers) are able to create coupons. code is the alpha numeric  (which should be unique - i need to try work that out). The coupon can be used by anyone only once. max_value is set by the user who creates it, and each time someone uses coupons, the 'used' should get automatically appended. suppose there are 10 coupons, every time a customer uses one coupon, the 'used' should get incremented by 1 till it reaches max_value. if it reaches max_value, coupon should be invalid. This is what I am trying to acheive. I hope you understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, maybe you can try like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

...
if form.is_valid():
    code = form.cleaned_data.get('code')
    order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, complete=False)
    coupon = Coupon.objects.filter(code__iexact=code, valid_from__lte=now, valid_to__gte=now).exclude(order__user=self.request.user,max_value__lte=F('used')).first()
    if not coupon:
        messages.error(self.request, 'You can\'t use same coupon again, or coupon does not exist')
        return redirect('store:checkout')
    else:
        try:
            coupon.used += 1
            coupon.save()
            order.coupon = coupon
            order.save()
            messages.success(self.request, "Successfully added coupon")
        except:
            messages.error(self.request, "Max level exceeded for coupon")
        
        return redirect('store:checkout')
```

**Explanation:** I am querying if a coupon is valid and has exact code. I am excluding any coupon which are already used by the user using reverse relationship between Order and Coupon. If you have any related name defined in the `Order` model, then the reverse query will be `exclude(<related_name>__user=self.request.user)`. I am also excluding any coupon which has value of `used` equals to `max_value`. Then I am taking the queryset's first value and using it in the `Order` object. Finally, I am adding +1 to the `used` attribute of `Coupon`.

### Update: add constrain in model

You can add a [`constraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#constraints) in model so that it does not exceed `max_value`:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F

class Coupon(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=Q(used__lte=F('max_value')), name="constrain-max-limit")
        ]
```

Comment: The coupon.used is incrementing..but it gets incremented above the max_value and the coupon is still active.

Comment: It should be like, the coupon shouldn't work if its exceed the max_value. How to give that condition. I tried giving a condition with 'if coupon', but its showing httpresponse as None.

Comment: I am already excluding it from queryset. Can you please try the updated answer?

Comment: I have also updated the answer with adding constraints in model so it will limit the value of used from database level. Also updated the rest of the codes to comply with the exception it will throw if validation fails on coupon save.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses, but still I am having the same issue, its getting incremented beyond max_value.

Comment: Um, sorry I don't get it why it might exceed max_value, even with the constraint added in model meta. what django version and database are you using?

Comment: I am using django 2.2 and postgres

Comment: I tested with same setup and found it works. Can please check if there is any other issue here? Also maybe try to clean up pyc files and run makemogrations and migrate again.

Comment: Sure. I will cleanup everything and  try again. I will get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Hello, yes, I just deleted the database and started everything from first and now it works fine. Can you tell me why you used 'F'  from django.db.models.
Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: F is used for accessing value from same instance in a queryset. documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions . I am using F to compare if value of `used` is less or equals to `max_value`.